# How can I avoid virtual call overhead when using crtp with common interface class?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, crtp

I am using CRTP for performance reasons, so I have this hierarchy :

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base{
  public:
    double do_sthing(){
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->do_sthing();
      }
};

class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA>{
  public:
    inline double do_sthing(){ ... }
 };

class DerivedB : public Base<DerivedB>{
  public:
    inline double do_sthing(){ ... }
  };
```

But now I want to put objects of type `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` in a vector and do the following kind of code :

```
 for(auto obj : my_vector) {
   obj->do_sthing();
 }
```

my solution was to create a common interface class from which `Base` will inherit :

```
class Interface {
  virtual void do_sthing() = 0;
};
```

But in this case I am incurring the virtual call overhead, and I did all the CRTP to avoid it. Is there a manner to avoid that? 
I thought of declaring the method `do_sthing` in `Base` as final.

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base{
  public:
  double do_sthing() override final{
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->do_sthing();
  }
};
```

Do I suffer the virtual call cost in the above?
Indeed, if I use virtual methods and plain old polymorphism, my performance hit comes from the vtable look up but also from losing the `inline` in the case of templates

Comment: If you are not going to know the size of the containers, and you are not going to know which type of object is in which index, you need run time polymorphism which means you should scrap the CRTP and just suffer the cost of the virtual call.

Comment: Have you actually measured that the virtual call overhead is one of the top two or three bottlenecks in your program? Unless you have done that then please try to avoid such optimizations (as the tend to make code even harder to read, understand and maintain).

Answer (score 2):

When you bring together different classes into a common structure known only at run time (like std::vector here), you can't avoid the virtual call overhead. This is a general C++ principle, for instance found also in std::function, std::any and so on. CRTP is no different in that respect.

Moreover CRTP (also known as static polymorphism) is primarily a tool for avoiding code repetition (without any performance overhead). It is not intended to speed up virtual function calls, because that is *dynamic* polymorphism stuff.

Beside this, you basically have two approaches to set up your classes:

One approach is to use a three-fold inheritance hierarchy, where I find it useful to separate the dynamic and static inheritance by different function names. Example:

```
struct Interface
{
     virtual ~Interface() = default;
     virtual double do_sthing_impl() = 0;
     auto do_sthing() { return this->do_sthing_impl(); }
};

template<typename Derived>
struct Base<Derived> : public Interface
{
     virtual double do_sthing_impl() const override { return this->do_sthing(); }
     auto do_sthing() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).do_sthing(); }
};

struct DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA>
{
     auto do_sthing() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Then:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface> > v;
v.push_back(std::make_unique<DerivedA>());
v.push_back(std::make_unique<DerivedB>());
```

Second alternative is **type_erasure**, e.g. via the following code (which is basically inventing an inheritance structure but without close coupling)

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base{ /* ... */ };

struct DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA>{ /* ... */ };

struct type_erased
{
     virtual double do_sthing() = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
struct type_erased_impl : public type_erased
{
     Derived d;
     type_erasure_impl(Derived d) : d(std::move(d)) {}
     virtual double do_sthing() const override { return d.do_sthing(); }
};
```

Then:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<type_erased> > v;
v.push_back(std::make_unique<type_erased_impl<DerivedA> >(DerivedA{}));
v.push_back(std::make_unique<type_erased_impl<DerivedB> >(DerivedB{}));
```

I prefer the second alternative, because it's more flexible and doesn't introduce a fixed inheritance structure. Rather, you can implement several type erased versions of the same class where you, according to the actual need, expose only specific functions.

Comment: I implemented indeed the first solution. My problem is that in that case, everytime I  do `for (it :v) {it->do_sthing();}` I will suffer the cost of virtual function lookup in the vtable, right? So why not use pure old polymorphism in that case as the two commentors said, as the whole point of CRTP is to avoid that virtual function call overhead

Comment: @volatile: Ok, but that's a misconception then -- as soon as you put the stuff into a vector, you can't get around virtual function calls (resp. type erasure in one of its implementations). CRTP doen't help here, because obviously `Base<DerivedA>`and `Base<DerivedB>` are different and unrelated classes. Nevertheless, this actually *is* "pure old polymorphism", but with another class in the middle.

Comment: Thanks. Again in the first solution, even if I will suffer the virtual function call, will I at least gain the inlining of the functions `do_sthing` in `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`?

Comment: @volatile (answering your question): in terms of performance, you lose nothing as compared to "plain old" dynamic inheritance (without CRTP). But you gain abstraction, in that you can avoid code repetition. That's relevant particularly when you have several derived classes.